# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libawt_xawt.so: libXi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to run an executable on remote Linux through Putty (SSH).

When I run the executable on remote Linux through Putty I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/user/xhs/tps/lnx32/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I execute `apt-file search libXi.so.6` I get:

```
libxi6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6
libxi6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6.1.0
libxi6-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6.1.0
```

Any idea? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924339/chromedriver-on-ubuntu-12-04-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libxi-so-6) did not help me

Answer (score 1):

An important difference would be the arch:

```
jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so
.../lib/x86_64...libXi.so.6
```

Which suggests that the 32-bit flavour of `libXi.so.6` should be installed.

Comment: I installed libxtst6:i386 but did not work

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? `ldd` might be a good next step, or possibly `strace` to see where the application is looking for things.

Comment: It means that I installed libxtst6:i386 but I still get the same error. BTW, If I execute `ldd xsetup` I get `not a dynamic executable`. By executing `sudo strace ./xsetup` I get a very long output that I cannot paste in this answer because the forum says that it is too long.

Comment: The missing library error comes from `libawt_xawt.so`; what happened when you ran `ldd` on that?